# Jar file is not loaded

Tags: jar, nullpointerexception, runtime-error, websphere, noclassdeffounderror

We are getting the null pointer exception when we run our application. But we are not sure about the specific error.

NullPointerException: com.rvw.tl.blend.ServiceWrapper.class [rvwEEMS.jar:?]

[rvwEEMS.jar:?] -> what actually it is saying in this file. Is it unable to locate the jar or is it unable to load the jar.

what this colon and question mark means after a jar name.

Added the rvwEEMS.jar in the websphere shared library and mapped it into our websphere application. Physcial file is also available in the path.

Comment: What is at the top of the stack? I'm unfamiliar with message text like that, and it's possible that the code at the top of the stack explicitly threw it, with that text, rather than it being generated automatically by the use of a null object.